# python abstract property setter with concrete getter

Tags: python

is it possible to use `abc.abstractproperty` to create a concrete getter but make the setter abstract so its different for each of the inheriting classes. I handle the setting of val different for each subclass.

eg.

```
@abstractproperty
def val(self):
    return self._val

@val.setter
def val(self, x):
    pass
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How I ended up doing it.

```
class C(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @property
    def x(self):
        ...

    @x.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self, val):
        ...

class D(C):
    @C.x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        ...
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: @Hagai I was using 3.5

Comment: Yes. However, nothing prevents the client of your `C` class from defining a derived class that does **not** implement the `@C.x.setter`-decorated `x(self, val)` method and still being able to instantiate it.

Comment: @otterrisk `x.setter` is an `abstractmethod` in `C` and thus always needs to be implemented in a class derived from `C`. Am I missing something?

Comment: `x.setter` is not the method. It *takes* an abstract method as an argument, and returns a new property that combines the new definition of `x` with the existing property bound to `x`, then binding `x` to the new property.

Comment: @gofvonx as per @chepner's comment: your statement would be true if you replaced `x.setter` with `x(self, val)`.

Answer (score 19):

You'll need a little bit of indirection. Define the setter as you normally would, but have it call an abstract method that does the actual work. Then each child class will need to provide a definition of *that* method. For example,

```
class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        self._val = 3

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val

    @val.setter
    def val(self, x):
        self._val_setter(x)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _val_setter(self, x):
        pass


class Child(Base):

    def _val_setter(self, x):
        self._val = 2*x
```

Then

```
>>> c = Child()
>>> print c.val
3
>>> c.val = 9
>>> print c.val
18
```

Comment: This looks like a workaround to me as you are not using `val.setter` directly in the derived class. Is there any reason why [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35347135/10466556) shouldn't be used?

Comment: I think they are similar, if not identical. I find my approach simpler to follow, though, or at least more explicit, as it doesn't depend on stacked decorators.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! As far as I understand the documentation suggests to use a stacked decorator for a setter of an abstract property: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty